# Does the second from clause in this LINQ query do anything?

Tags: linq

I am trying to simplify a C# method that includes the following query:

```cs
var matchingDeviceKeys =
    from dev in data.Elements("Key1")
    where dev.Element("Key2").Element("Key3").Element("VendorID").Value == device.Vendor &&
        dev.Element("Key2").Element("Key3").Element("ProductType").Value == device.ProductType &&
        dev.Element("Key2").Element("Key3").Element("ProductCode").Value == device.ProductCode
    from rev in dev.Element("Key2").Element("Key3").Element("Key4").Elements("MajorRev")
    where rev.Attribute("Number").Value == device.MajorRevision &&
        rev.Attribute("DefaultMinorRev").Value == device.MinorRevision.ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)
    select dev.Element("Key6").Element("Key7").Element("Key8");
```

The "rev" target for the second from clause is never used in the select line, making me wonder if that entire second from clause is doing anything.  If it is doing something, what is it doing?

My apologies for obfuscating the element names.  I have to be careful in sharing proprietary code.

Comment: Wastes CPU time?

Comment: Second `from` in your query is like INNER JOIN. It filters out records from first `from`, if there is no matching record in second recordset. If you care about speed, do it via `join` operator.

Comment: @SvyatoslavDanyliv There is no reference to `dev` in the `where` for `rev` so how is there any join/filter?

Comment: My fault. I thought `device` is `dev`. Then you cannot use `join`. But second query still has affect.  If there is no any record In second recordset,  whole result will be  empty.  From other side if there are `M` records in second, all records from first recordset will be duplicated `M` times.